# NullPointerException after checking with if statement

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I have the following code:

```
        Map<BigInteger, AttributeValue> values = getParameters(elementHandler);

        AttributeValue value = values.get(attrID);
        AttributeValue auxValue = null;
        if (auxAttrID != null)
            auxValue = values.get(auxAttrID);

        try {
            if (value == null) {
                // some code here
            }
            if (value != null) {
                assert (value != null) : "value is null";
                if (value.getValue() == null ) {
                    // some code here
                } else if (auxAttrID != null && auxValue != null) {
                    // some code here
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error at getting attribute value (attr#" + attrID + ", auxAttrId#" + auxAttrID + ")", e);
        }
        return value;
    }
```

It produces `NullPointerException` at line

```
if (value.getValue() == null )
```

right after assertion.

`AttributeValue` is a simple POJO class. Why this happens and how can I fix it?

Comment: Your output is inconsistent with the code you have posted.

Comment: What is there in the getValue() method?

Comment: what does your `getValue()`method do?

Comment: I guess we will need a [Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), because  this shouldn't ideally happen.

Comment: I think the Exception appears inside the `getValue()` method.

Comment: Mean that the `value` object is `null`

Comment: @bmscomp:  There's *several* things guaranteeing that `value` itself isn't `null` in that code block.

Comment: getValue() method returns String

Comment: do you paste your pojo class code

Comment: Add your `AttributeValue` class into your question.  It'll be a *lot* faster to look at that than to throw darts at the wall, which is what we've been reduced to for now.

Comment: my suggestion will be try to recompile your project and run it again, there is no possibility to have this output with provided code. unless there is some doggy code in `getValue` method

Comment: Add the exception stack trace, please.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: With all those null checks we can safely say that the `value` isn't null and isn't causing the `NullPointerException`. Like @maja said, the exception occurs inside the `getValue()` method. Could you post the code of everything inside that method and, more importantly, could you post the entire `StackTrace` of the error like @TagirValeev suggested. The `StackTrace` will point you to the place where the exception is actually occuring and will most likely also state what object is null inside that method. By posting a `StackTrace` the people at StackOverflow can help you better with Exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It produces NullPointerException at line `if (value.getValue() == null )`

```
if (value != null) {
    //...
    if (value.getValue() == null ) {
        //....
```

The above `if` condition states that, `value` is not `NULL` when you are invoking `value.getValue()`. Still you are getting `NullPointerException` for `value.getValue()` means the exception is coming from method `getValue()` (e.g you are trying to access any class attributes with a `NULL` object etc).

Edit your question with the implementation of `getValue()`.

Use [getStackTrace()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getStackTrace()) to find out where the problem occurs. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors) for more information.

Comment: Yes, you're not technically wrong, but this much is definitely obvious to us all.  It's not really explaining what specifically is causing the NPE, and until we get more information, we don't know that information.

Comment: Shame on me. You are right: `getValues()` method produces NPE.